# Delphi: access violation error when accessing SOAP Server from proxy enabled windows7 pc and SOAP Server hangs

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-2009, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe

I've spent a few weeks googling and trying various changes to the code. I EVEN tried put log file in the SOAP server but no error found in the code.

I have got a SOAP server written in delphi XE. Its very straight forward. Interface has got only one function

```
type
  { Invokable interfaces must derive from IInvokable }
  IIirate = interface(IInvokable)
  ['{153E0531-5EAB-49E3-B824-62447AF6F0A9}']

    { Methods of Invokable interface must not use the default }
    { calling convention; stdcall is recommended }
    Function ProcessRequest(Request: TSOAPAttachment): TSOAPAttachment; stdcall;
  end;
```

I have got one client with proxy enabled pc. Only when he login to my SOAP server its hangs and no one else can access the server unless I recycle the IIS application pool. But I can see soap attachment cache files keeps coming into the server. 
Funny thing is if I commented out the ProcessRequest function in interface unit then same situation arise.

Comment: What is the implementation part of this interface? In fact, what is the initialization code of the class instance? If the IIS server hangs, it is probably the server side which is faulty. You can attach the IIS process to the Delphi debugger, then debug your server side.

Comment: It seems like Delphi bugs.  Implementation is very simple it does just validate user. Process request takes user name and password as a soap attachment and return true or false as soap attachment.
IIS doesn’t hang only the SOAP server hangs. IIS works fine

Comment: I think your problem is in deserialization of the soap request, you may want to give that a look, I'd recommend using a third party solution such as RemObjects SDK or try .NET, it may be harder at first, but it's going to get easier in time, while with delphi, it's only going to get worst...

Answer (score 0):

You could try soapUI to test against your server (https://www.soapui.org/) to eliminate the possibility that the client app is doing something that is making it hang.
However, one client should not really be able to make it hang. Is the threading model that your SOAP server uses a multi-threaded one? The link has info on COM multi-threading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/choosing-the-threading-model